# Under what conditions are the products of inertia (off diagonal elements of inertia tensor) non-zero?

Tags: tensor-calculus, moment-of-inertia

Under what conditions are the [products of inertia](http://www.google.com/search?as_q=&as_epq=product+of+inertia) (off-diagonal elements of [inertia tensor](http://www.google.com/search?as_q=&as_epq=inertia+tensor)) non-zero? It seems that for many objects, constructing the moment of inertia tensor results in something like the following:

\begin{matrix}
I_{xx} & 0 & 0\\
0 & I_{yy} & 0\\
0&0 & I_{zz}
\end{matrix}

From a glance, it seems like this is due to some agreement between the distribution of the objects mass, and the way the co-ordinate system has been aligned. For example, we'd align our axes parallel to the sides of a rectangular prism. Moving the origin by the parallel axis theorem often introduces non-zero product of inertia terms, as well.

What specifically causes this difference? Is there always a set of axes for any object, rotating around any point where they are zero? Is this a property of rotating around some point other than the center of gravity?

Comment: There is a theorem that says you can find a coordinate system for which the inertial tensor is diagonal for *any* mass distribution. Look in any any graduate mechanics text and most upper-division ones. So ... under all conditions other than the ones needed to achieve diagonalization?

Comment: Related: http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/66350/