# Relation between inertia tensor and moment of inertia about an axis

Tags: homework-and-exercises, rotational-dynamics, terminology, tensor-calculus, moment-of-inertia

As far as I understood, we define two quantities:

1. [Inertia Tensor](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moment_of_inertia#The_inertia_tensor) - a $3\times3$ matrix, which describes the object "mass" of rotation in relation to a **certain point,** helping us calculating rotations around any axis in 3D-space.
2. [Moment of Inertia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moment_of_inertia) - a **scalar** which describes the object "mass" of rotation in relation to a **certain axis.**

And my question is:

- Is my understanding correct?
- How can we reach the Moment of Inertia of some arbitrary axis, while being given the Inertia Tensor?

Comment: Suggestion: Besides _inertia tensor_ and _moment of inertia_  also ask about _products of inertia._

Comment: Related: http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/66350/2451 , http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/60843/2451

Comment: Thanks @Qmechanic, It helped me understanding the subject, but I still have not reached a final conclusion about my second question "How can we reach the Moment of Inertia of an arbitrary axis, while being given the Inertia Tensor?"...

Comment: In short: By projecting the inertia tensor to that axis.

Comment: @Qmechanic As a moderator, should I delete this question? or would you like to post an answer to this question, so I can accept it?

Comment: In principle, there's no difference for using inertia tensor and moment of inertia when the axis aligns exactly on one of the **principal axes**.  However, the stability will be completely different.  See [**this**](http://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/67957/stability-of-rotation-of-a-rectangular-prism) for your further interest.