# Moment of inertia- a tensor quantity

Tags: tensor-calculus, rotational-kinematics, moment-of-inertia

The moment of inertia is a tensor and the  matrix contains nine elements. The off-diagonal elements are like Ixy, Ixz, Iyx and so on. Ixy = mxy. 
But M.I. = mass × (perpendicular distance of the particle from the axis)^2.
So what does this x×y signify in the relation for Ixy?

Comment: Your definition of M.I. in terms of the square of the distance from an axis is a simplified definition that applies only to certain tensor components. It is not the full tensor definition.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is the physical significance of the off-diagonal moment of inertia matrix elements?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/66350/)

Comment: Also [What's the physical significance of the off-diagonal element in the matrix of moment of inertia](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/60843/)